# How can I force a view-based NSOutlineView to reload the views for an item?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, appkit, nsoutlineview

I have a datasource/view-based `NSOutlineView`, which has the ability to change the type of data represented in a row, even though the actual `item` object reference stays the same. When this mutation occurs, one of the columns needs to load a different `NSTableCellView`. I've tried doing the following after the mutation:

```
[outlineView reloadItem:updatedItem reloadChildren:YES];
```

When that gets called, the following `NSOutlineViewDataSource` methods get called:

```
-outlineView:isItemExpandable:
-outlineView:child:ofItem:
```

But this method never gets called:

```
-outlineView:viewForTableColumn:item:
```

How can I force the `NSTableView` to actually reload the views for a specific item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use

```
- (void)reloadDataForRowIndexes:(NSIndexSet * nonnull)rowIndexes columnIndexes:(NSIndexSet * nonnull)columnIndexes
```

to ensure that your `viewForTableColumn` delegate method is called.